# Raspberry pi doesn't boot after config.txt was deleted

Tags: raspberry-pi, config, boot, launch, raspbian

As i said in the title I deleted the config.txt file in the raspberry pi(raspbian). Why is that you might ask ? Well before that the raspberry pi was starting but could not boot. The following error message was on the screen : " error  -110 transfering data sector 133646 ". The same message was printing on the screen with the last number incrementing of 1, every second.

So I thought the file system was corrupted and wanted to resolve that, problem is I deleted the config file wich seemed to be the problem, maybe that wasn't so smart.
Now the raspberry pi is not even booting which means that I don't even see error message on the screen and cannot access the raspberry.

My question is : how can I get the pi to boot again ? Can you give me a good config.txt file so that i can try it with that ?

Thanks a lot for your time and expertise.

Comment: I have not tried deleting my /boot/config.txt, however mine is completely empty and it boots fine.  So, just try adding a completely empty config.txt.  My suspicion is that you've got other data corruption though, so you may need to re-image your SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the found the solution, I used chkdsk from Windows. It restored and repaired the file system so all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you delete the config.txt file, it definitely won't boot, because it's literally in /boot (in newer Raspbian versions, it wil be in /boot/firmware). Try making a config.txt file in the correct directory and adding this in(this is my config.txt file, it will turn the status LEDs off, but you can remove this):

```bash
  GNU nano 7.2                /boot/firmware/config.txt
# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]
# Other configuration options

# Disable the ACT LED
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=none

# Disable the PWR LED
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=none
```